# Spring using ModelAndView addObject not show only for lists

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am trying to display objects in a jsp page that are loaded using addObject() and returned via a controller.But when I try to add one object it shows on jsp page. But with `list` it doesn't show.

here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView printWelcome(ModelMap model){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("arcane") ;
   //List<Pattern> patternList=patternDao.patternList();
    List<String> list = getList();
    mav.addObject("lists", list);
    mav.addObject("channa", "gayan");
    return mav;
}

private List<String> getList() {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("List A");
    list.add("List B");
    list.add("List C");
    list.add("List D");
    list.add("List 1");
    list.add("List 2");
    list.add("List 3");

    return list;

}
```

And here is my Jsp code section

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${lists}">
          <li>${listValue}</li>
          <li>${channa}</li>
     </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

It shows the `value of "channa" correctly`, but not `content in "lists"`. Anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: So what is the out your getting?

Comment: Hum, I tried your code, it works fine. What's your output and the output you expect?

Comment: I expect to out put list of values "List A","List B",... but it only shows "gayan" (value of attribut "channa")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the mistake.

need to define JSTL on top of the jsp page to work

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jsp view as below:

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${lists}">
          <li><c:out value="${listValue}" /></li>
          <li>${channa}</li>
     </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: it gives the same output

Comment: please, can u test by delete these code mav.addObject("channa", "gayan"); and  <li>${channa}</li>.. And them result is same?

Comment: found the mistake.. thanks for your time. I just forgot to define jstl